# wait for writestream to finish before executing next function

Tags: node.js, fs, synchronous

I have two functions.
The first function reads all the files in a folder and writes their data to a new file.
The second function takes that new file (output of function 1) as input and creates another file. Therefore it has to wait until the write stream of function 1 has finished.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function f1(inputDir, outputFile) {
    let stream = fs.createWriteStream(outputFile, {flags:'a'}); // new data should be appended to outputFile piece by piece (hence flag a)
    let files = await fs.promises.readdir(inputDir);

    for(let file of files) {
        let pathOfCurrentFile = path.join(inputDir, file);
        let stat = fs.statSync(pathOfCurrentFile);
        if(stat.isFile()) {
            data = await fs.readFileSync(pathOfCurrentFile, 'utf8');

            // now the data is being modified for output
            let result = data + 'other stuff';
            stream.write(result);
        }
    }
    stream.end();
}

function f2(inputFile, outputFile) {
    let newData = doStuffWithMy(inputFile);
    let stream = fs.createWriteStream(outputFile);
    stream.write(newData);
    stream.end();
}

f1('myFiles', 'myNewFile.txt');
f2('myNewFile.txt', 'myNewestFile.txt');
```

Here's what happens:

- 'myNewFile.txt' (output of f1) is created correctly
- 'myNewestFile.txt' is created but is either empty or only contains one or two words (it should contain a long text)

When I use a timeout before executing f2, it works fine, but I can't use a timeout because there can be thousands of input files in the inputDir, therefore I need a way to do it dynamically.

I've experimented with async/await, callbacks, promises etc. but that stuff seems to be a little to advanced for me, I couldn't get it to work.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Why are you using half asynchronous and half synchronous file I/O?  Pick one or the other.

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry that's a leftover from trying out different things

Comment: @jfriend00 What would this look like 100% sync?

Comment: 100% synchronous, you'd just open the file with `fs.openSync()` and use `fs.writeSync()`.  What kind of app is this code in?  Is it a server process?  Or just a single user processing script?

Comment: FYI, the code you show won't even run because you show `await` in a non-async function.

Comment: It's a single user processing script. And sorry about the 'await', that's also a leftover that I forgot to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked about a synchronous version, here's what that could look like.  This should only be used in a single user script or in startup code, not in a running server.  A server should only use asynchronous file I/O.

```
// synchronous version
function f1(inputDir, outputFile) {
    let outputHandle = fs.openSync(outputFile, "a");
    try {
        let files = fs.readdirSync(inputDir, {withFileTypes: true});
        for (let f of files) {
            if (f.isFile()) {
                let pathOfCurrentFile = path.join(inputDir, f.name);
                let data = fs.readFileSync(pathOfCurrentFile, 'utf8');
                fs.writeSync(outputHandle, data);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        fs.closeSync(outputHandle);
    }
}

function f2(inputFile, outputFile) {
    let newData = doStuffWithMy(inputFile);
    fs.writeFileSync(outputFile, newData);
}

f1('myFiles', 'myNewFile.txt');
f2('myNewFile.txt', 'myNewestFile.txt');
```

Comment: @c0rnfl4k3s - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.